# How does this Python import work?

Tags: python

I have two files in the same directory, and there are no `__init__.py` files anywhere:

```
c:\work\test>tree
.
|-- a
|   `-- a
|       |-- a1.py
|       `-- a2.py
`-- b
```

one file imports the other:

```
c:\work\test>type a\a\a1.py
print 'a1-start'
import a2
print 'a1-end'

c:\work\test>type a\a\a2.py
print 'a2'
```

The import succeeds even when run from a completely different location:

```
c:\work\test\b>python ..\a\a\a1.py
a1-start
a2
a1-end
```

I'm running

```
c:\work\test>python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

and my PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variables are not set

```
c:\work\test>echo %PYTHONPATH% %PYTHONHOME%
%PYTHONPATH% %PYTHONHOME%
```

How does `a1.py` find `a2`?

Comment: I would hazzard a guess that like PHP, Python would evaluate multiple locations to find files, including the current working directory?

Comment: The current working directory is `test\b`...

Comment: the script is running from a however, forgive my lack of python knowledge, but php and I believe most languages would treat this scenario similarly, when you type .. that's changing the working directory for that script only

Comment: yes as the answer below states, the directory containing the input script, eg a :).

Comment: The answer below is correct, but the directory where the script is located is different from the current working directory -- i.e. if you print `os.getcwd()` in `a1.py` it will print `c:\work\test\b` (not `c:\work\test\a\a`).

Comment: yes because your asking for the os current working directory, not the script (ie the answer in black below), probably my terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quote from the [module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) (emphasis mine):

"When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:

- **the directory containing the input script** (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default."

Comment: Ah, I got confused because I didn't see a reference to `test\a\a` anywhere in `sys.path` (which starts out with `['', 'c:\\python27\\lib..`).

Comment: @thebjorn: `''` refers to the boldfaced part of ofrommel's answer.  See [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).